# Big O of a recursive function

Tags: algorithm, recursion, big-o

I'm learning Big O notation but am stuck when it comes to recursion. This is a fairly new topic to me, I was taught to solve this either using substitution or the master method. I don't know how I would apply this to pseudo code though.

```
    def isThis(n): 
        print(n) 
        if (n == 1):
            return True
        if (n == 0): 
            return False
        if (( n % 3) == 0):
            return (isThis(n/3))
        else:
            return False
```

My understanding is that this algorithm will run O(n) if we use T(n) = aT(n/b) + f(n), where a = 1, b = 3 and d = 1

'a' is number of recursive calls

'b' is factor of the subproblem

'd' is exponent of the running time outside of the recursive call.

But I have no idea if I'm doing this correct or tackling it in the completely wrong way.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: In your analysis you define , but don't use it. On the other hand, you use (), but don't define it. Anyway we cannot give an assessment of what happens "outside of the recursive call", so it should not be mentioned here.

Comment: @trincot I think `d` is supposed to describe `f(n)`, since `f(n)` can be called "what happens outside of the recursive call": `f(n) = O(n^d)` or `f(n) = O(log(n)^d)`, but then it should be zero.

Comment: Let's hear the clarification from @Jean-Paul...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Master Theorem formula using Landau notation is:

```
T(n) = aT(n/b) + O(n^d)
```

Where :

- **n** is the size of the input,
- **T(n)** is the time complexity of the algorithm for a problem of size n.
- **a** is the number of sub-problems generated by the algorithm during each recursion.
- **n/b** is the size of the sub-problems. This assumes that the algorithm divides the initial problem into sub-problems of size n/b.
- **O(n^d)** is, expressed as a Big O notation, the cost of merging the sub-problem solutions and all other non-recursive operations performed.

In the algorithm you've given, the function `isThis(n)` performs
a recursion based on dividing n by 3 until n
reaches 1 or some other stopping condition. So, we can consider n to be the size of our input, and:

- **a = 1**, as the recursion generates only one sub-problem at each
  iteration (There will only be a maximum of one call to `isThis` inside `inThis`).
- **b = 3**, because n is divided by 3 at each recursion (each call of `isThis`)

To determine O(n^d), we see that the cost of the verification operation (condition and return) is constant, regardless of the size of the the input n.
So O(n^d) = O(1), thus **d = 0**.

Now with a, b and d, we can check which case of the Master Theorem match our case :

- Case 1 : if d < log_b(a) then T(n) = O(n^log_b(a))
- Case 2 : if d = log_b(a) then T(n) = O(n^d log_b(n))
- Case 3 : if d > log_b(a) then T(n) = O(n^d)

In our case, we have log_b(a) = log_3(1) = 0

And we also have d = 0.

So we are in the second case, and the complexity of your function is :

O(n^d log_b(n)) = O(n^0 log_3(n)) = O(log_3(n)), simplified as **O(log(n))**.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense now - appreciate it :)

Answer (score 2):

Your code runs in `O(log(n))` arithmetic operations of course, since in the worst case it performs as much operations as there are ternary digits. If you want to apply the master theorem, your case is case 2 from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)), since `f(n) = O(1)`.

Note that this asymptotic description is in arithmetic operations. This code does not run in `O(log(n))` time since every arithmetic operation does not run in `O(1)` time.

Comment: thanks @maxplus, can you please elaborate what you mean by "since in the worst case it performs as much operations as there are ternary digits" ? I don't quite follow.

Comment: @Jean-PaulAzzopardi, consider the work this function performs. It looks at the remainder of `n` modulo 3. If it is 0, it divides `n` by 3 and continues. If we write `n` out in ternary numeral system (`42 = 1*27 + 1*9 + 2*3 + 0*1 = 1120_3`), this function loops over the digits starting from the least significant until it encounters a non-zero digit (unless `n` is a zero initially). So it performs at most as much operations as there are digits (up to a multiplicative constant), `O(log(n))`.